# How to set spinners drop down view width?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to reduce width of spinner's dropdown view.
my dropdown view is `CheckedTextView`.
I set width to `CheckedTextView` 300dp but It didn't help. It took whole display anyway.

P.S . I wanted to post picture also but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're setting the `layout_width` attribute instead of `width`.

```
<CheckedTextView 
    android:id="@+id/myCheckedTextView"
    android:layout_width="width_you_want_in_dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

You can also do it programmatically like this:

```
myCheckedTextView.getLayoutParams().width = width_you_want_in_pixels;
```

Hope this helps!